# White background breaking my canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to draw several shapes to a canvas and I'm running into a strange issue. When I try to draw a white rectangle on the canvas before drawing my shape, the shape never shows up. What am I doing wrong?

Sample code:

```
// drawing a white background
// This breaks it. If I comment thiese two line out, it works.
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, Canvas.width, Canvas.height);

// Draw the rectangle
ctx.lineWidth = LineWidth;
ctx.strokeStyle = Color;
ctx.beginPath();
var startPos = Ordinates[0];
ctx.moveTo(startPos.start.x, startPos.start.y);
ctx.lineTo(startPos.stop.x, startPos.stop.y);
for(var i = 0; i < Ordinates.length; i++){
  if(i === 0) continue;
  ctx.lineTo(Ordinates[i].stop.x, Ordinates[i].stop.y);
}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

[And here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/bwn7d1o0/)

If you comment out the 2 lines that draws the white background rectangle, it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are filling it with white, since that is your fillstyle and you don't set it to another color. **Unless of course that is what you want to do...**

Comment: How do I fill it with white and just have the black stroke?

Comment: set the fillStyle just before `ctx.fill()`, i'll update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF"; // <-- set the fill color to white
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, Canvas.width, Canvas.height);

// Draw the rectangle
ctx.lineWidth = LineWidth;
ctx.strokeStyle = Color;
ctx.beginPath();
var startPos = Ordinates[0];
ctx.moveTo(startPos.start.x, startPos.start.y);
ctx.lineTo(startPos.stop.x, startPos.stop.y);
for(var i = 0; i < Ordinates.length; i++){
    if(i === 0) continue;
    ctx.lineTo(Ordinates[i].stop.x, Ordinates[i].stop.y);
}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill(); // <--- filling with white, while the background is still. you can remove this line btw
ctx.fillStyle = '#000000'; // <-- now we set it to black
ctx.fill(); // <--- filling with black now
```

also, if you want to see an outline of the path:

```
ctx.stroke();
```

this draws the outline of it in the right color.

But in a reply to v.rouge you just said you wanted it white with a black outline:

```
ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
ctx.fill();
ctx.stroke();
```

done :-)

Answer (score 1):

Fillstyle is white. Drawing is white. Might explain.

Comment: I want the fill to be white. I just want the black stroke with a white fill. if I change the background to green, it still doesn't show up.

Comment: Try setting the stroke color to black then?

Comment: is that not what i'm doing on line 17?

Comment: See the other answer from Doxick